# How Encode 10bit 1080p .mkv file to 10bit 720p .mkv using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, hevc

How Encode 10bit 1080p .mkv file to 10bit 720p .mkv using ffmpeg.

Can anyone provide the full command line from beginning to end with best quality and the least file size?

Comment: What have you tried so far please, and at which step are you having difficulty? Have you tested something simple such as `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -filter:v scale=720:-1 -c:a copy OUTPUT.mkv` yet?

Comment: File size vs quality has been addressed here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1028051/57576 A simple resize would be easy enough to add to the mix....